# Using multiple search criteria in SQLite LIKE clause based on a nested SELECT

Tags: sqlite, join, select, inner-join, sql-like

I have a list of full-paths in the "SOURCE" table in SQLite and a list of specific filenames (which will obviously be part of the path) in a SPECIFICFILES table.

I want to find the files in the SOURCE table based on their filenames. I'm trying to use "LIKE" to match part of the path, but the search below returns nothing:

```
select * from SOURCE WHERE FullPath like (select char(39)||'%'||"SPECIFICFILES"."Filename"||'%'||char(39) FROM SPECIFICFILES);
```

(Char(39) is a quote in ASCII).

This query returns nothing.  Is this possible in SQLite please or do I need to use C# to fire off each query in turn?

Adding some sample data:

```
Table SOURCE:
FullPath
C:\My Directory\MyFile.txt

Table SPECIFICFILES:
Filename
MyFile.txt
```

Comment: Please include some sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by joining the tables:

```
SELECT s.*, f.* 
FROM SOURCE s INNER JOIN SPECIFICFILES f
ON s.FullPath LIKE '%\' || f.Filename || '%';
```

I'm not sure why you used in your code `CHAR(39)`.
Is it part of the paths?
Also if the filename is at the end of `FullPath`, without any trailing `\`, there is no need to concatenate the wildcard `%` at the end:

```
SELECT s.*, f.* 
FROM SOURCE s INNER JOIN SPECIFICFILES f
ON s.FullPath LIKE '%\' || f.Filename;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=00fdf09fdb45b5e1f89a49e9ad3be5ff).

Comment: Thank you very much.  Much appreciated.  I'd included the char(39) in a misguided attempt to replicate the syntax used by LIKE (in that the string is normally enclosed in quotes).